# Why undefined? Even if the this pointer is pointing to the same object and also the strict mode is used

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";
const data = {
firstName: "myName",
lastName: this.firstName,
};
console.log(data.lastName);
```

> Output is undefined.
> Can anyone explain why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` does not work like that. When you are defining your object literal (`data`), `this` does not point to that literal - to see what `this` actually is, do a `console.log(this)`.

You can solve your problem by modifying your code like this:

```
"use strict";
const data = {
    firstName: "myName"
}
data.lastname = data.firstname;
```

Also, I recommend [reading up on how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to avoid confusion in the future - `this` is a bit weird in Javascript.